# Border for svg elements

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I am working with svg and its dom manipulation. I want to create a border for a group of svg elements positioned inside the `<g>` tag. How do I do this? Is it possible to create circular / elliptical boundaries also? I am using the jQuery SVG library. Thanks in advance

```
<g>
<rect x="20" y="30" width="200" height="300" fill = "red"/>
<circle cx="40" cy="50" r="25" fill="blue"/>
</g>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot add a border to containers like `<g>` or `<svg>`, since they are not supposed to render anything directly by themselves. You may want to look how [this demo](http://files.myopera.com/MacDev_ed/svg/coords/sandbox_dims.svg) is implemented using the cross browser implementation of [getScreenBBox()](http://my.opera.com/MacDev_ed/blog/getting-screen-boundingboxes-in-svg);

Answer (score -17):

In your CSS you could add:

```
rect {border: 1px solid #00f;}
```